# Setting package in dojo build configuration

Tags: dojo-build

I am using dojo 1.10 and got 'missing dependency' errors when creating the build.

my profile.js:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        ......
        packages:[{
            name: "dojo",
            location: "dojo"
        },{
            name: "dijit",
            location: "dijit"
        },{
            name: "dojox",
            location: "dojox"
        },{
            name: "app",
            location: "app"
        }],

        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: [ "dojo/dojo", "dojo/i18n", "dojo/domReady", "app/f1/f11/mymodule"],
                customBase: true,
                boot: true
            },
            "app/f1/f11/mymodule": {
                 include: [ "app/f1/f11/myModule" ]
            }
        }
    };

})();
```

my dojoConfig.js:

```
var dojoConfig = {
  packages: [{
                name: "f1",
                location: "C:/absolutePathToApp/app/f1"
            },{ 
                name: "f2",
                location: "C:/absolutePathToApp/app/f2"
            }]
};
```

myModule.js has required dependencies like:

```
define("f1/f11/myModule", [
        "f1/someModule", 
        "f2/otherModule",
        ...
```

When I run the build with --dojoConfig dojoConfig.js in the command line, I got all the dependency error for the modules that are under f1 folder but not f2. I have no idea why it can set the path alias for f2 but not f1, is it because myModule is inside f1?

Any advice or discussion would be much appreciated!